# User emulation - Browser automation

Tags: selenium, language-agnostic, browser-automation

I have a website where users should every day perform the following tasks:

- Log in with user/password
- Select from a filter the date of the day
- Click on a link that will let them download a csv file that they will import in a database.

Of course I can't change the website, but I would like to automate this.

I'm testing Selenium, but I should set up a complete environment to create a scalable import process where I can launch several process together.

My idea is to setup a server that will:

- emulate a browser
- log in into this website
- perform the actions, including select, click and wait instructions
- save the csv stream into a file
- import into a sql sb

What would be a good framework or service to start?

Thanks for your time

Comment: what do you mean by server based?

Comment: be more clear if you want an specific answer..

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted) should be a good place to read.